# Porting iOS app on Mac using Chameleon project

Tags: ios, macos, uikit, porting, osx-chameleon

I have developed an app for iOS in which I have used MPMoviePlayerController to show videos.No issues there.The app works well.

Now I want to port the same app on Mac.I am a novice in Mac programming so I decided to search 'anything' which can help me port my app on mac and I got [Chameleon](http://chameleonproject.org/).I tried the sample app 'MultiApple' and it worked but when I tried integrating in my app,it gives error like UIKit framework couldn't be found.

Somewhere I am doing a horrible mistake.

Can anybody please help me in this integration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am also in the middle of porting a relatively big application(~20k LOC, excluding all 3rd party dependencies) from iOS to Mac, although took more time than expected, I am still fairly happy with what Chameleon provides. Due to incomplete implementation and some limitation, I have also forked the official Chameleon for my own usage:

https://github.com/jerryrt/Chameleon

Your problem is mainly caused by incomplete/wrong project setup, which indeeds Chameleon lacks a detailed document, except the sample projects provided for reference. I am getting here mainly by checking the sample projects' setup piece by piece. I will not fully cover the detailed process here, but provide what a correct project setting looks, especially with MPMoviePlayer integrated.

[image: importing Chameleon]

[image: a working project setup]

Btw, if your original iOS project is heavily XIB based, I don't recommend Chameleon for this purpose.